# Implementing a VOIP feature

Tags: node.js, reactjs, twilio, voip

I have a server that I **built with nodeJS and express** and I want to add a VOIP feature to it. What I mean is **I have a twilio phone number**, and while I know how to use webhooks in order to reply with SMS messages or programmable voice, I can't figure out how to answer the calls from the computer (the server is **running a frontend built with React**).

I have absolutely no knowledge in this area and so I am sorry if I haven't provided enough details.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You already tagged twillio with it so why don't you start by reading it's docs.

Comment: I read the docs and I didn't understand how I can do it. The docs is how I implemented the call webhooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd recommend checking out our [Programmable Voice JavaScript SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript).  This JavaScript library lets you create a VOIP connection to Twilio through which you can make or receive phone calls.  There is a [Node.js Quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/quickstart) you can download and follow.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It was just what I needed! thank you very much.